# WP toggler menu for all screens

Tags: wordpress

I want to enable the mobile toggler icon for all screens. I'm not sure if this possible to do on wordpress.
I'm using "Airi" theme.

I just want when someone visit my site, he will not gonna see the menu items. He will only see the toggler icon. And when he hits the icon, then it will expand the menu items.
See the attached screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6TDk.png)

Comment: Please share any code you have tried.

Comment: Actually I did nothing because I'm not getting how to start!

Comment: Please have a look on this site, https://www.dreamandgarden.com/

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. When someone visit to my site, the will see the toggler icon instead of menu items

Comment: This question is not for this site then. You need to research a few things and try some approaches. If the code try is not working then you can post that code in a question and get help.